# How to make an efficient database design with a null Foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I want to make a database that when I query it, it will give me, user data, sector, and sub sector(If user not have sub sector it will give me NULL). 
Every user have a sector, every sub sector have a sector. But the problem is not every user have a sub sector. 
Is there any better and efficient way than this database I design? In the user table I make the sub sector column can be NULL.

```
Table : user
+------------+----------+
|   Column   |   Type   |
+------------+----------+
| id_user    | INT (PK) |
| name       | Char     |
| sector     | INT(FK)  |
| sub sector | INT(FK)  |
+------------+----------+

Table : sector
+------------+----------+
|   Column   |   Type   |
+------------+----------+
| id_sector  | INT (PK) |
| sector_name| Char     |
+------------+----------+

Table : sub_sector
+----------------+----------+
|   Column       |   Type   |
+----------------+----------+
| id_sub_sector  | INT (PK) |
| sub_sector_name| Char     |
| id_sector      | INT (FK) |
+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: I suggest giving your foreign keys and primary keys more consistent names.  The way you have it now, a lot of your WHERE clauses are going to be WHERE sub sector = id_sub_sector.  Making them both id_sub_sector will help reduce coding errors.

Comment: Sometimes FKs are more trouble than they are worth.  Forget about them and let's look at the `SELECTs` that you will need to perform.  Then we can design optimal `INDEXes`, and _finally_ put in what FKs make sense.  _FKs are not mandatory._

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want to declare a table with a null in a PK, or are you trying to write a certain query, or what? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. For code questions give a [mre]. When clear this will be a faq.. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: If id_sub_sector can be null in table sub_sector then it can't be a SQL PK & it can't identify a row & there can be multiple rows with it null. Yet you mark it PK. You don't need a null id_sub_sector in table sub_sector to have a null sub sectorin table user. Please say exactly what you want, without talking about a null in a PK. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. (Where are you 1st stuck following a published design method?)

Answer (score 0):

If each subsector has a unique sector, then in your schema you have a redundancy, when a user has a subsector. To eliminate such redundancy you could design a schema like this, in which you have a table for sectors AND subsectors together.

`User(user_id, name, sect_id)` where `sect_id` is a not null foreign key for the table `Sect`

`Sect(sect_id, name, type, super_sect)` where `type` has two different values, one for subsector and one for sector, `sect_id` and `name` are the id and name of the sector or of the subsector, and `super_sect`, not null only when type is sub_sector, is a foreign key for the table Sect.

You could also enhance the efficiency by giving a consistently different id to sector and subsector, for instance odd/even, or integer from different intervals.

Comment: The subsector not have a unique sector, it can be around 1 to 4 sub sector that can have same sector.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DavidNoya, if a subsector can have multiple sectors, why in your solution the subsector table has a single foreign key for the sector table?